# Detect scroll events with bootstrap-modal modalOverflow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a number of tooltips a date pickers used in my modal. How can I detect if the overflow modal has been scrolled so I can either reposition any open floating elements and reposition them according to the modal scroll position?
Thx

window.scroll is not firing!

An example of this is available here: Long modals (bottom of page)
http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already answered your own question, but I would add that it's working this way as well:

```
$("#modalcontact").modal().on('loaded.bs.modal', function(){
   $(this).parents('.modal-scrollable').scroll(function(){
      //Do stuff
   });
});
```

I've struggled to manage to work with shown event, but it was because the content was loaded remotely.

Answer (score 6):

OK, I sorted it.
The scroll event doesn't propagate to the document level of the DOM so `$(document).on` doesn't work.
I got around it with this hack.

This **did** work.

```
$(document).on("shown", "#modalcontact", function() {
    $(".modal-scrollable").unbind("scroll");
    $(".modal-scrollable").scroll(function(){
        //do stuff
    });
});
```

This **didn't** work.

```
$("#modalcontact").modal({
    shown: function (){
        $(".modal-scrollable").scroll(function(){
            //do stuff
        });     
    }
});
```

This **didn't** work.

```
$(document).on("scroll", ".modal-scrollable", function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

Comment: Which element did you set modal-scrollable class on?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).on('scroll', '.modal-scrollable', function(){
//your code here
});
```

The scroll event handler can be bound to more than just the window.

Comment: Nothing :( It's really driving me nuts

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, whereas the earlier answers didn't for some reason. But I am opening the modal window using code, so that I can dynamically fill it with content before it is shown.

```
 $('#modalcontact').modal('show');

 $(".modal-scrollable").unbind("scroll");
 $(".modal-scrollable").scroll(function () {
    $('body').append('Hey hey hey!');
 });
```